# bug in cardinality [elastic search]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query to get ALL UNIQUE values on field 'customId'.

The query I am using is -

```
{
   "_source": ["customId"],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "prevAddressMap.*"
      ],
      "query": "1st st"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "customId.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response -

```
{'distinct_count': {'value': 3499}}
```

But when I put these values into a set, I get answer as 4, which is the correct answer.

```
d = []
for h in res['hits']['hits']:
    d.append(h['_source']['customId'])
d = set(d)
print(len(d))
```

Any reason for this difference?

Comment: The aggregation actually looks okay, so I'm inclined to trust the results from the aggregation.  Are you sure that the python code reading hits into a set is actually scrolling over all of the search results?  Note that by default, you'll only get the first 10 hits back from any query, so is it possible that your python code is only counting the `customId` field from the first 10 matching documents?

Comment: Remember that the carnality aggregation doesn't return an exact count of the term occurrence (you can see more information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate)). This may be the reason for you to don't have exact counts when running the aggregation on ElasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Will check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prevAddressMap.*.keyword solved the issue.